# How to update CSS via typescript

Tags: css, angular, typescript

I have a pie chart that I have hidden by default as such:

```
 .sub-chart {
    min-height: 300px;
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 24px;
    visibility: hidden;
 }
```

However, upon a user filtering on a different chart, I want to change the css visibility attribute so that the chart is no longer hidden.

How am I able to update css via the typescript component file?

Comment: you can use `<div class="sub-chart" [style.visibility]="condition?'visible':null`">` and make the condition true/false. As style has priority over class, you see the "div"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bku4cn) create attribute

```
isDivVisible="visible"
```

in html give as its style

```
<div class="sub-chart" [style.visibility]="isDivVisible"></div>
```

in component change `isDivVisible` like below

```
this.isDivVisible="hidden";
```

Comment: This works, but it would arguably be better to swap a css class in and out instead of directly tweaking the style in code. You can bind to [ngClass] to do this. See https://angular.io/api/common/NgClass

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using `ViewChild` decorator and `Renderer2` service like so:

1) In the component template add a template variable:

```
<my-element #myElement></my-element>
```

2) In the ts file:

```
@ViewChild('myElement') myElement: ElementRef<any> // the argument type can be HTMLElement / HTMLDivElement / component etc.

constructor(private renderer: Renderer2) {}

myMethod() {
 this.renderer.setStyle(this.myElement.nativeElement, 'visibility', 'visible');
}
```

ViewChild, Renderer2, ElementRef must be imported from `@angular/core`.

> You can also use `addClass` and/or `removeClass` methods instead of
>   `setStyle` for the renderer.
>
> If you are using Angular 8 you need to pass a configuration object as a second argument to the @ViewChild like so:
>   `@ViewChild('myElement', { static: false })`. The `static` property must be set to `true` if it is used in OnInit life cycle hook (for Angular 9 as well).